# Spring integration : Best way to avoid polling the directory for same file in the same polling context?

Tags: spring-integration

I am using inbound channel adapter for poling the directory and setted the poling interval to 10000. But ,poller keeps on poling the same file again and again until file processing is done and results in exceptions .

I tried using various file list filters.
AcceptOnlyOnceFilter - it will poll the file only once . But , I do want to poll the file when it comes after some time .

AbstractFileListFilter(modified time stamp ) - it will poll the file next time only if it is modified . But . I do want to poll the file if it comes after some time without any modifications .

Appreciate any response .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a task executor (or queue channel) anywhere in the flow; that way, the file is processed on the poller thread which won't look for another file until the poll completes.

If you need to asynchronously process files in parallel, the first step should rename the file so the next poll doesn't find it.